# Strange Phone behaviour after system reset

Tags: lumia-520

I reset my Lumia 520 recently using Lumia recovery tool.After reset my phone is behaving strange.
1.Suddenly call gets disconnected displaying the error message 'System Busy'
2.Phone looses Wifi connectivity even if i am in the range of the WiFi network ,other devices remain connected to the same wifi hotspot.

Please advise .

Answer (score 1):

The only sensible advice I can give here would be to take your phone to your dealer, and have them look at it. 'System Busy' could be caused by a memory failure.